# NSAlert without bouncing dock icon

Tags: cocoa, macos

If you put up an `NSAlert` while your app is in the background your dock icon starts bouncing and keeps on bouncing until you switch back.

I find this annoying.

Does anyone know how disable that for a single app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your own subclass of NSApplication, and implement something like this:

```
- (int)requestUserAttention:(NSRequestUserAttentionType)requestType
    {
        if (dontDoThatBouncyThing) {
            return 0;
        }
        return [super requestUserAttention:requestType];
    }
```

Don't forget to change "NSPrincipalClass" in your Info.plist from NSApplication to your own NSApplication subclass.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. The constant bouncing Dock icon is the bane of my existence! Thank you :)

Comment: works on High Sierra as well. Only Objective C though, swift class crashes

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'd recommend it, but there is a Haxie that may help: [Dock Detox](http://unsanity.com/haxies/dockdetox).

They allow you to intercept the bouncing and do other stuff, I think.

A quick google showed up:

```
- (void)cancelUserAttentionRequest:(int)request
```

But I really don't know if this will work for your purposes.